# Send emails with powershell with only BCC

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell

I need to find a way to send to 30 people emails, i dont want them CC, i want each of them to recive the mail as it look this mail is for him only.
I know i can use outlook and leave the "to" empty and only put those mail addresses at BCC. this is a good solution, but i need it automated.
i cannot find a way to use send-mailmessage powershell cmd to do the same.
close as i get is to send it to myself and then BCC everyone, or running a loop sending 1 mail after another with the -to argument. both are not good for me.
is there anyway i can do it?

Comment: It is not possible. An email "To" is mandatory.

Comment: Question is how is it done in outlook? you can send multiple messages with -to, you can just add them Bcc

Comment: In my overly paranoid mindset; this sounds rather nefarious/spammy to me. ;-}, as the only reason to do this is to hide the source. This is why I always train users to inspect email headers. If you can trace the TO or it's not normal, just delete it using Outlook rules or manually and report to security. just say'n. However, you can put any email in the to section you choose. It does not have to be a real one. You'd just get an NDR on your end for that. There is no legitimate reason for a mail/domain admin or any normal user to hide a genuine source/sender info other than spam or phishing.

Comment: my solution was to point the `to` address to me ... [*grin*]

Comment: @DavidPostill: If you're talking about email in general, that's completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with David.

Based on my research, the -To parameter is a required parameter, which may help to prevent it from becoming a spam engine.
So for your requirement of Powershell, you could try to put your own email address or something like "noreply@noreply.com" in To field.

Answer (score 0):

The requested actions are not available using the cmdlet Send-MailMessage, however you can use the .net class `net.mail` to achieve what you want. Please see the below that you could incorporate into your script.

```
$SMTPserver = "<SMTP Endpoint>"
$fromAddress = "Something@Somedomain.tld"
$subject = "<Subject>"
$emailbody = "<body of email>"
$bccAddresses = @("someone@something.com","someoneelse@somethingelse.com","anotherone@anotherdomain.com")

$mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($SMTPserver)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

Foreach ($emailAddress in $bccAddresses){
    $msg.bcc.add($emailAddress)
}

$msg.Subject = $Subject
$msg.Body = $emailbody
$msg.From = $fromAddress


$mailer.send($msg)
```